# limit of the sequence $a_n=n^{1/n}$

Tags: limits

I use Rogawski, Multivariable  Calculus, chapter 1.1, problem 63

Determine the limit of the sequence:

$a_n=n^{1/n}$

I believe I understand the explanation given in the student's manual:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (\ln x/x)=0$$ and this leads to $e^0=1$. (I assume they used the rule of L'Hospital)

Would the following be an acceptable answer also:

$a_n=n^{1/n}$  and since $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1/n)=0$ as and since any 'number' (including the 'number' infinity) to the zeroeth power equals $1$, therefore $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{1/n}=1$.

Comment: No, you can't use this type of argument; $\infty^{0}$ is an indeterminate form.  (Otherwise, you could show that $(e^n)^{1/n}\rightarrow0$.)

Answer (score 2):

Your proof doesn't work. You are looking at a sequence in indeterminate form. That is, in the limit you are getting $\infty ^0$ which is undefined. There is a trick you can use for these types of problems.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{\ln(n^{\frac{1}{n}})} \\ = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{{\frac{1}{n}}\ln(n)}$$ Now let's just focus on the exponent of $e$ separately. Note that the exponent is in indeterminate form, namely $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. By L'hopitals rule, we know $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1}{n}}\ln(n) =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1}\\ =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \\ = 0$$

So $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{{\frac{1}{n}}\ln(n)} = e^0$$

Answer (score 1):

What you said about $\infty^0=1$ is not valid, since $\infty^0$ is an indeterminate form, which can take any value depending on what functions are approaching 0 and $\infty$. For instance consider the sequence $b_n = n^{1/\log n}$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=\infty^0$, since the exponent approaches $0$ while the denominator approaches $\infty$. But we also have that $b_n =e$ for all $n$ (since $\log(b_n)=\frac{1}{\log n}\cdot\log n=1)$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=e$ as well! This shows $\infty^0=e$, and other examples can make $\infty^0$ be any value you want.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $n^{\frac{1}{n}}>1$. Say
$$
n^{\frac{1}{2n}}=1+a_n,
$$
where $a_n>0$. It suffices to show that $a_n\to 0$. We have
$$
\sqrt{n}=(1+a_n)^n\ge 1+na_n\ge na_n,
$$
and hence
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}>a_n>0,
$$
which implies that $a_n\to 0$.